# How to get a global isFetching status for queries & mutations with RTK Query

Tags: javascript, caching, redux, rtk-query

A **query** returns statusses like **isFetching**, very nice. This is on a **query level**.

But if we have **a lot of queries** and we would like to monitor if one of them is **isFetching**, to show a **global loading indicator** for example.

So now I want to have **something like**: https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/background-fetching-indicators#displaying-global-background-fetching-loading-state

How can I make a **global** loading indicator when **any queries are fetching** (including in the background) with **RTK Query**?

Comment: You ask for a development guide not for a specific issue. If you face a specific issue during your implementation consider to open a new question.